# how to count the number of characters entered and action on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, character

Hi I am fairly basic in jQuery, and got stuck in a script:

```
//hide all radio buttons first

$('#q11_6_1').parent().hide();
$('#q11_6_2').parent().hide();
$('#q11_6_3').parent().hide();
$('#q11_6_4').parent().hide();
$('#q11_6_5').parent().hide();

//check the length of the open text box

var other2text = $('#q11_6_other').val().length;
$('#q11_6_other').keypress(function(){

//if at least one character has been entered, then I want to show all radio buttons

if(other2text>=0)
{
    $('#q11_6_1').parent().show();
    $('#q11_6_2').parent().show();
    $('#q11_6_3').parent().show();
    $('#q11_6_4').parent().show();
    $('#q11_6_5').parent().show();
}

//else I want to hide all

else
{
    $('#q11_6_1').parent().hide();
    $('#q11_6_2').parent().hide();
    $('#q11_6_3').parent().hide();
    $('#q11_6_4').parent().hide();
    $('#q11_6_5').parent().hide();
}
});
```

The first part of the "if condition" is working, however when I have cleared all texts in q11_6_other, those radio buttons won't hide. I think the "else" section is not working, but not sure how to get around it.

Much appreciated with your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your variable `other2text` inside the event hander function:

```
$('#q11_6_other').keypress(function(){
    var other2text = $('#q11_6_other').val().length;
```

Also, I suggest you use `keyup` instead of `keypress`. If you do that however, you need to change `other2text>=0` to `other2text>0`

Answer (score 0):

Your other2text variable is currently populated once on page load. What you want is make it run everytime you press a button, so put that variable inside the function:

```
$('#q11_6_other').keypress(function() {
    var other2text = $('#q11_6_other').val().length;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the variable other2text inside the event handler

```
$('#q11_6_other').keypress(function() {
    var other2text = $('#q11_6_other').val().length;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
$('#q11_6_other').keypress(function() {

var other2text = $('#q11_6_other').val().length;
```